# Flask - failure marshalling simple object

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to marshal a simple data structure in Flask, as below:

```
{
    "globalNum": 1.23,
    "perResultData": [
        {
            "string1": "test string",
            "num1": 1.25
        },
        {
            "string1": "test",
            "num1": 1.22
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm modelling  that structure like this:

```
testmodel = api.model('Model', {
    'globalNum': fields.Float,
    'perResultData': fields.List(fields.Nested({ 
            "string1": fields.String,
            "num1": fields.Float
    }))
})
```

When I try this setup (as per minimum failing code below), if I browse to localhost I get a warning 'No API definition provided.' and the Flask console shows:

```
File "/home/mikea/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/swagger.py", line 574, in register_model
    if name not in self.api.models:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Flask works perfectly when I comment out the '@api.marshal_with(testmodel)' line. 
Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, please? Thanks very much

Full code:

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api,fields

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

testmodel = api.model('Model', {
    'globalNum': fields.Float,
    'perResultData': fields.List(fields.Nested({ 
            "string1": fields.String,
            "num1": fields.Float
    }))
})

@api.route('/')
class incomingRequest(Resource):
    @api.marshal_with(testmodel)
    def post(self):
        return {"globalNum":3.2,
                "perResultData":[
                    {
                        "string1": "test string",
                        "num1": 1.25
                    },
                    {
                        "string1": "test",
                        "num1": 1.22
                    }
                ]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was here - https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/292

When nesting models, you have to wrap them in the model class, like the below:

```
testmodel = api.model('Model', {
    'globalNum': fields.Float,
    'perResultData': fields.List(fields.Nested(api.model({ 
            "string1": fields.String,
            "num1": fields.Float
    })))
})
```